# How to debug Mockolate for unit testing

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, mockolate

While unit testing in `actionscript-3` with `mockolate` I have run into quite a few problems/errors:

```
Error: No Expectation defined for Invocation:[FloxyInvocation invocationType=GETTER name="propertyName" arguments=[]]

Error: 1 unmet Expectation
```

Mockolate errors and debugging are poorly documented and searches bring up no results, so solving these problems get very tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No expectation defined error is thrown when the function you are testing expects the specified invocation type and name:

```
  Error: No Expectation defined for Invocation:[FloxyInvocation invocationType=GETTER name="propertyName" arguments=[]]
```

Can be solved with:

```
mock(object).getter("propertyName").returns(someValue);
```

Unmet expectation error can be thrown when you created a mock statement (a `getter` or `setter`) but there is no `getter` or `setter` defined for the variable you are `getting` or `setting`.

```
Error: 1 unmet Expectation
```

Can be solved with:

```
    public function get variable():String {
        return _variable;
    }

    public function set variable(value:String):void {
        _variable = value;
    }
```